# Mule: Backend Microservice Loadbalancing

Tags: mule, load-balancing

I have this application with Angular based UI & Spring based Microservices in the backend. Mule sits between these two and orchestrates traffic between them.

While I know a lot about front end load balancing with HAProxy to redirect traffic between Mule nodes. I was interested in learning if  mule can redirect traffic in the backend without having to use an external loadbalancer. I want the Mule to backend interaction to be as seamless and simple, is there some kind of software load balancing mule can do in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

For **On-Premise** there is **NO** inbuilt \ embedded load-balancer

You can still go through link below which could help to imporove some performance using clustering.

[Mule Runtime High Availability (HA) Cluster Overview](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/mule-high-availability-ha-clusters)

For CloudHub Mule deployments there are certain provisions.

[Cloudhub Dedicated Load Balancer](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-dedicated-load-balancer)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved using "first-successful" connector but it goes to the next block within it only if the first one fails and so on.